# My next.js code for dynamic content and routing isn't working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm following a YouTube tutorial for next.js and i got stuck on a very beginning point. I'm trying to create a dynamic content and routing for my website with the codes below but there is an error:

```
import Link from 'next/Link';

const people = [
    {v: 'car', name: 'bruno'},
    {v: 'bike', name: 'john'},
    {v: 'airplane', name: 'mick'}
]

export default function Details (){
    return <div>
        {people.map( e => (

        <div>

            <Link as={'/${e.v}/${e.name}'} href="/[vehicle]/[person]">
            <a>Navigate to {e.name}'s {e.v}</a>
            </Link>

        </div>
        

        ))}
        
    </div>
}
```

The dynamic routing for the code above is working fine actually. But when i go to my details page, the content is looking like "${e.name}'s ${e.v}" this.  It doesn't look like according to my parameters. I believe the problem occurs because of this line:

```
<Link as={'/${e.v}/${e.name}'} href="/[vehicle]/[person]">
```

I tried to change " ' " this quotation mark to this " ´ " back quote mark but that also doesn't work. Could you please help me?

I also get this error in my Developer Tools console. I changed the fb.me link for a purpose.

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the top-level render call using <div>. See blablafb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.
    in Link (at Details.js:13)
    in Details
    in App
    in Unknown
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Provider
    in AppContainer
```

Comment: This is the back tick you should use `

Comment: You need to add a `key` attribute to the top-level div where you map over people's array. The key attribute takes a unique id.

Comment: I made your change and now it looks like this: 
<Link as={`/${e.v}/${e.name}`} href="/[vehicle]/[person]">
            <a>Navigate to {e.name}'s {e.v}</a>
</Link>

But this also doesn't work. My URL also is looking like this: http://localhost:3000/$%7Be.v%7D/$%7Be.name%7D

Comment: what is your expected url can you give a example?

Comment: My expected URL is like "http://localhost:300/vehicle/jahid" and the content of the page for that url should be "jahid's vehicle". Its a dynamic routing (in theory lol). And could you please specify key attribute for me, I can't get it where to put key attribute.

Comment: you have `/[vehicle]/[person].js` inside your pages directory?

Comment: You may also need to add `passHref` attribute to the `Link` tag:
<Link as={\`/${e.v}/${e.name}\`} href="/[vehicle]/[person]" passHref>

Comment: Yeah, i have, and routing for that directory works fine. the problem is to map keys from people const and having it written for both url and content. I believe it is a problem about key attribute too, but I don't know where to put my key attribute and how

Comment: passHref also doesn't work for me.

Comment: use this <Link as={`/${e.v}/${e.name}`} href={`/${e.v}/${e.name}`}> use backtick as stackoverflow removes them

Comment: What doesn't work? the code I showed you works: <Link as={\`/${e.v}/${e.name}\`} href="/[vehicle]/[person]" passHref>
Do you expect the pages will open by just adding their links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `/pages/index.js` file you change single quotes ' with back ticks ` to permit string interpolation, and add a `key` attribute to the top-level `div` where you map over people's array:

```js
import Link from "next/link";

const people = [
  { v: "car", name: "bruno" },
  { v: "bike", name: "john" },
  { v: "airplane", name: "mick" }
];

export default function Details() {
  return (
    <div>
      {people.map((e, idx) => (
        <div key={idx}>
          <Link href="/[vehicle]/[person]" as={`/${e.v}/${e.name}`} passHref>
            <a>
              Navigate to {e.name}'s {e.v}
            </a>
          </Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then create `/pages/[vehicle]/[person].js` where you display different content based on the link you clicked on:

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Person() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { vehicle, person } = router.query;

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        Vehicle: {vehicle}, Person: {person}
      </p>
      Go back{" "}
      <Link href="/" passHref>
        <a>Home</a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you literally saved my life mate :D Appreciate it!